# Is there performance/compiler benefits when using tuple vs struct whenever possible?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, struct, tuples

Is there performance/compiler benefits when using tuple vs struct whenever possible?

For example in this case where

- you don't need protocol conformance,
- you don't need functions,
- all variables are readonly.

.

```
typealias SomeModel = (
    name: String,
    id: String
)
```

vs

```
struct SomeModel {
    let name: String
    let id: String
}
```

Comment: Please check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35154272/7512091

Comment: more details in https://james919.github.io/swift-tuples-vs-structs

Comment: I understand the posts talk about struct vs tuple but I don't see details about performance benefits

Comment: Please describe your performance tests and procedure for determining the answer to this question in an actual use case.

Comment: Upvoted. If there's no difference, then the ability to typealias should be targeted for deletion from the language due to redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a formal answer to your question but here is a very basic test comparing creation times.

```swift
import Foundation

func duration(_ block: () -> ()) -> TimeInterval {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    block()
    let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    return end - start
}

struct Person {
    let first: String
    let last: String
}

let total = 99999
let structTest = duration {
    for _ in (0...total) {
        let person = Person(first: "", last: "")
    }
}
let tupleTest = duration {
    for _ in (0...total) {
        let person = (first: "", last: "")
    }
}

print(structTest, tupleTest)
```

The results were:
`1.3234739303588867 1.1551849842071533`

Answer (score -4):

Create following function to calculate a time for operations. Put blocks of your code as its argument and try to see a difference by yourself:

```
func duration(_ block: () -> ()) -> TimeInterval {
  let startTime = Date()
  block()
  return Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
}
```

Comment: Good advice, but this is not an answer.

Comment: This is not good advice. Measuring time intervals using Date is not accurate. Use CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() instead.